# android : Changing font size/style duplicate the linear layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

A fragment is launched which has a list view in it, from an activity.
Now being on this screen switch to setting and change the font size/style the list view duplicates, changing the font size/style again make the list view 3 times and so on..
I am not getting why it is happening??

I checked the onCreateView(....) of fragment if the the view is not null then return the same view.

```
private view myView;
.
.
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   if(myView!=NULL) return myView;
    .
    .
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag, container, false);
    .
    .
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: :O What? Your listview is creating again and again on change of size from settings??

Comment: yes..actually not only listView but all in that fragment layout.